# SQL constraints on update problems

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I am currently studying SQL and I had a question about a constraint that I must create for an exercise.

Given 2 table:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
a1 integer PRIMARY KEY,
a2 integer CHECK (a2>10))

CREATE TABLE B (
b1 integer PRIMARY KEY, b2 integer))
```

and a many to many relationship table between A and B

```
CREATE TABLE R (
rID integer PRIMARY KEY,
a1ID integer REFERENCES A (a1),
b1ID integer REFERENCES B (b1))
```

I want to create a constrain on table B such that: when a new instance of B is added, there should be at least 5 and at most 10 instances of A Being related to B.

This is how I did it:

1) a trigger on insert into B:

```
CREATE triggerA BEFORE INSERT ON B 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upCons();
```

2) create a function that check the number of instance of A related to B:

here is my problem, can I just count the number of instance of R by doing this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION upCons() RETURN trigger AS $$
DECLARE x integer;
BEGIN
SELECT count(rID) INTO x FROM R;
IF (x<5 OR x>10) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'insert condition not met';
END IF;
END; LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

OR I do the same by counting the instances of A in the relationship.

Is this a good approach to the problem? Should I do it differently and is this correct to begin with

Comment: Maybe I understood something wrong, but wouldn't this constraint keep you from inserting anything into B, if R contains too few or no entries at the time the trigger is created?
Oh, and the condition (x<5 AND x>10) is also against logic - x can't be both smaller than 5 and larger than 10. I believe it should be OR.

Comment: That is waht i am wondering,

Comment: i don't really understand constraint that much at the moment, but this seem to restrict the creation of new instance of B if there are too few instances of A in the relationship. Which is what i want if i understand the constraint correctly

Comment: Then you'd have to apply the constraint after you have populated table R with at least 5 entries. Otherwise you will not be able to insert anything into table B, because you have too few entries in table R. You won't be able to insert anything into table R then either, since it references table B.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a constrain on table B such that: when a new instance
>   of B is added, there should be at least 5 and at most 10 instances of
>   A Being related to B.

This constraint seems unreasonable (or perhaps even impossible), because at the time of inserting an entry into B (or A), there cannot be any relations already referencing the new entry. Referencing an entry (using a foreign key constraint as you do) requires the entry itself to already exist in the correct table. And according to your trigger, if you don't have enough relations in R, you cannot insert anything into B. Therefore you have effectively made your tables B and R read-only, since table B insertions are denied by your trigger and table R insertions by the foreign key constraint that requires any reference to table B to already exist in table B.

Comment: its actually a question on an exam from a previous year and i've been struggling with it for a while, on the exam, the constraint is as follow: " Whenever a new instance of B is added to the DB, there should be at least 5 and at most 10 instances of A being related with the new B instance"

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (x<5 AND x>10) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'insert condition not met';
```

This is supposed to be OR instead of AND, right?

Comment: Right my mistake, does it make sense with a OR?

Comment: You're still missing the connection between B and A.  
Right now you are inserting B only when there is more than five and less than ten items in the table.  
You need to supply your procedure with the primary key for B and then check table A for more than five and less than ten entries related to B.

Comment: Could i use something like this?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a1ID) INTO X FROM R